# Find process that are listening to a port without sudo privileges

Tags: process, port

How to find the `process ID's` of the processes that are listening to a particular `port` , when you don't have the `sudo` privilieges ?

Comment: You can't, that's part of the Unix security model.

Comment: Even if the process is owned by the user that fires the cmd to find them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find your own processes with:

```
lsof -i :port#
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to list processes on Jenkins which are listening on a port, and when they started:

```
lsof -t -i :4848 | xargs ps -o pid,etime,start,command -p
```